# How to change the button color on right click paste option?

Tags: jquery

I have a input box and a button. When I **CTRL+C** and **CTRL+V** the color of the button will change. But if I right-click copy-and-paste, the button doesn't change color. How can I make the button change color when I right-click copy-and-paste?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harishkumart2191/6eoxj6ps/1/)

**Script**

```
$(document).on('keyup click', "#inputfield", function() {
    var txtEntered = false;
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        txtEntered = true;
    }
    if (txtEntered)
        $("#btn").removeClass().addClass('green');
    else
        $("#btn").removeClass().addClass('red');
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to also be watching #inputfield for changes? Also, what browsers are you testing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('input', "#inputfield", function () {
    var txtEntered = false;
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        txtEntered = true;
    }

    if (txtEntered) $("#btn").removeClass().addClass('green');
    else $("#btn").removeClass().addClass('red');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `input` and `propertychange` event like this.

Code snippets:

```
 $(document).on('input propertychange', "#inputfield", function () {
    var txtEntered = false;       
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        txtEntered = true;
    }
    if (txtEntered)
        $("#btn").removeClass().addClass('green');
    else
        $("#btn").removeClass().addClass('red');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/beb3a1kk/)

**Note:** It will work on modern browsers alone

Answer (score 0):

Use the onpaste event in HTML:

```
<input id="inputfield" type="text" onpaste="onPasteTest()"/>
<button id="btn"  class="red">Click</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function onPasteTest(){
    var txtEntered = false;
    if($(this).val() !== ""){
            txtEntered = true;
            }

    if(txtEntered)
        $("#btn").removeClass().addClass('green');
    else
        $("#btn").removeClass().addClass('red');
}
```

It didn't work in your fiddle, but [here's a working example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onpaste).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can try using `change` event, works with IE as well. On text boxes this event fires on losing focus and only if the contents has changed.

```js
var btn;
$(function() {
  $('#inputfield').on('change', toggleColor);
  btn = $('#btn');
});

var toggleColor = function(e) {
  btn.toggleClass('err', '' === this.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));//takes care of white spaces 
};
```

```css
.err {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='inputfield' />
<input type='button' id='btn' value='Click me !' />
```